# отличие array_splice от array_slice

Tags: php, массивы

Вот срабатывает как надо:

```
$a = [0,1,2,3,4];
echo array_sum(array_splice($a,2,3,true)) . "<br>";
```

А тут как надо срабатывает только первая:

```
$a = [0,1,2,3,4];
echo array_sum(array_splice($a,0,3,true)) . "<br>";
echo array_sum(array_splice($a,1,3,true)) . "<br>";
echo array_sum(array_splice($a,2,3,true)) . "<br>";
echo array_sum(array_splice($a,3,3,true)) . "<br>";
echo array_sum(array_splice($a,4,3,true)) . "<br><br>";
```

что я не понимаю, как оно работает?

Comment: Постарайтесь давать __вменяемый__ заголовок вопросам.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что я не так делаю?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/970340/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%8e)

Comment: @u_mulder приведите пример вменяемого заголовка для этого вопроса

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ прост, всё дело в одной букве:

> Функция [array_splice()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-splice.php) — Удаляет часть массива и заменяет её чем-нибудь ещё

т.е splice работает как ctrl + x, если не указать чем заменяем вырезанное

> Функция [array_slice()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-slice.php) — Выбирает срез массива

slice же в свою очередь работает как ctrl + c

Comment: читаю про одно, пишу другое, жесть

Comment: вообще давно их путал, теперь запомню

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
$a = [0,1,2,3,4];

function ar($params) {
    return array_sum(array_splice($params[0],$params[1],$params[2],$params[3]));
}

echo ar([$a,0,3,true]).'<br>';
echo ar([$a,1,3,true]).'<br>';
echo ar([$a,2,3,true]).'<br>';
echo ar([$a,3,3,true]).'<br>';
echo ar([$a,4,3,true]).'<br>';
```

Результат

```
3
6
9
7
4
```

Если я правильно понял "вопрос"